# WP Future Posts are not being published

Tags: php, wordpress, scheduled-tasks

> ```
> $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
> $date = strtotime("+60 minutes");
> $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date);
> $postId = wp_insert_post(array(
>     'post_author' => 1,
>     'post_category' => $kategori,
>     'post_content' => $aciklama,
>     'post_status' => 'future',
>     'post_date' => $date,
>     'post_date_gmt' =>$date,
>     'post_title' => $adi,
>     'post_excerpt' => '',
>     'post_type' => 'post',
>     'tags_input' => $etiketler
> ));
> ```

I have written the code above. It inserts post to the database and i see the post as scheduled in the article list. But It doesn't publish when time comes(now + 60minutes). What am I missing? Should I write anything else to make it publish when time comes?

Comment: Is your timezone correct in your Settings -> General page?

Comment: Yes, it seems correct. Also there is another bot working as expected. Unfortunately, I am not able to see its codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this date from WordPress function,

```
$cur_date = current_time('mysql');
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($cur_date) . "+60 minutes");
```

May be help you.

Comment: This worked. Thanks. I must have done some mistake with date. :)